# Set default Repository for git on devOps after fork

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, devops, project-management

I work in project born under in another repository on DevOps. After some weeks of works we decide that this development need to be a separate product.

So, I create a new project in DevOps and from first repository I create a fork to my new project.

[image]

Now, every time I create a pull request DevOps ask me to push my code not in "new repository" but in old repository and I need to remember to change it every time.

[image]

How can I set my local master as the main master for local?

Mat

Comment: can you clarify this `set my local master as the main master for local`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, I'm assuming by your decision `this development need to be a separate product` the fork is intended to never find its way back to the source repository.

### You want to *import* a repository into the new project

You've created a ***Fork***. Forks are really meant to support `Inner Source workflow` for when you don't have access to the original project (contributing to someone's project on GitHub).

Now that you've forked the repository, Azure DevOps is expecting that you want to put your suggested changes into the main line of the fork source repository.

Instead of Forking your repo use the import repository function in your new project.

[image]

This allows you to then choose your **projectA** repository by its clone url.

[image]

With your newly cloned repository in **projectB** you can decide if you want to clone it into a fresh local workspace or if you want to use the [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem) command to change your local repository to point to **projectB** as `origin` instead of **projectA**.

Comment: Thank Josh, you are really right. My first option is not correct. So I used your suggestion "Import" from my fork and after import process I deleted the fork. Now it works has I expect

Comment: @JoshGust If importing a repository how to apply updates from the parent (original) repository to the now imported repository? When forking, it is easy to push new changes down from the parent (where it was forked from) down to the forked repo.

Comment: @JStrahl if you're in a situation where you need the ancestor repo to stay in sync with the origin, I think you should be using a fork and not doing this import route. The OP was asking for a scenario where the origin was to be completely and forever separate from its ancestor.